# Nginx configuration for wordpress site in folder

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I want to setup a wordpress site in a folder on my current site.
I have a main app running, but I want to route all the requests that start with `/folder` to that wordpress site, that it's located in a different folder on the server.

I've been struggling with the nginx configurations for a couple of days.

I also have 2 subdomains each with its own server blocks that I'm not posting here because I don't think it's relevant (but please let me know if otherwise)

Here's my abbreviate nginx configuration:

```
server {
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location /folder/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /folder/index.php?$args;
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/folder)(/.*)$;
        }
    }
}
```

Right now when I browse to the folder it's downloading the `/folder/index.php` file.

Side questions:

- Are there online resources to debug a nginx configuration
- Is there a "log" statement that we can put on the nginx configuration to help understanding what blocks are being triggered

Comment: please describe the business problem you are working on and what is the business related question in here, I don't see here any relevant research nor what you are done to solve it

Answer (score 1):

I've finally managed to find the solution.
Posting here to it helps someone in the future:

```
    location ^~ /folder {
        alias /home/user/folder;
        index index.php;

        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /folder/index.php last; }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.+)?$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        }
    }
```